# exclude artifacts from publishing in artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I have a list of artifacts out of which I need to exclude some artifacts from publishing to Artifactory repository. How can I do so, currently I am using below task:

```
project('examples') {artifactoryPublish.skip = true }
```

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. What's the question?

Comment: When I use this task inside subprojects block it does not skip. When I use this task inside allprojects block it does not skip. When I use this out of both the blocks it still does not skips. This is how I am using it:   allprojects {
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'artifactory'
project(':cli') { artifactoryPublish.skip =true }

Comment: which version of the Artifactory gradle plugin are you using? which version of gradle?